# Error Strongly Naming DLL Without Source Code

Tags: windows, batch-file, strongname

I'm attempting to take a DLL that is not strongly named and then strongly name it without needing to have the source code, since I will not always have the source code, only the DLL. When I try and run the batch file with the below code to accomplish this I get an error. Here is the code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\ildasm.exe" .\targetFile.dll /out:.\Signed\targetFile.il

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ilasm.exe" .\Signed\targetFile.il /dll /key=.\targetFile.snk /output=.\Signed\targetFile.dll
```

The error I get is the following:

```
.\Signed\targetFile.il(43) : error -- Failed to extract public key: 0x80070005
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I have permissions to all involved folders including the MacnineKeys folder in ProgramData.

Comment: This is not a scripting/programming related issue. It is about the utility `ildasm.exe`. Please read the provided documentation.